# How to create shorthand for a rule without ambiguity?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have this in my grammar: (INF is short for influence)

```
inftype 
: 'INF' ('Attack'|'A')
| 'INF' ('Defend'|'D') 
| 'INF' ('Recharge'|'R')
;
```

This leads to ambiguity between INFA and INFAttack. Is there anyway to resolve this bar making two rules?

This does not work either:

```
inftype 
: 'INF' ('Attack'|'Defend'|'Recharge')
| 'INF' ('A'|'D'|'R')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

> inftype 
>       : 'INFAttack'
>       | 'INFDefend'
>       | 'INFRecharge'
>       | 'INFA'
>       | 'INFD'
>       | 'INFR'
>       ;

Well, here is how it should be done :) I figure it out.

Comment: I recommend to create explicit lexer rules for all your literals. This allows better control of the invocation (by reordering the rules) and will give you explicit token names, instead of automatically created ones. With the knowlege in mind that ANTLR matching is greedy by default (longest match wins) you can then easily define various "keywords" plus single lentter tokens and have them all working together.